# Como hago para que me aparezca windows en el grub?

Tags: linux, windows, windows10, windows-installer

Instale Manjaro anoche y elimine una particion pequeña de 1 gb para poner usarlo como swap ahora tengo que termine la instalacion tengo el problema de que no me aparece windows en el grub ni tampoco puedo entrar a el por la bios, entre por manjaro y vi que aun esta instalado

Ayuda amig@s como vuelvo a tenerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes instalar **os-prober**, esta herramienta detecta otros sistemas operativos.

```
sudo pacman -Sy os-prober
```

Después recarga grub con:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Si necesitar hacerlo en el momento de la instalación de grub en el disco:

```
sudo pacman -Sy os-prober # Lo normal es instalar grub-bios con pacstrap en la instalación inicial del sistema, en tu caso Manjaro debería haberlo instalado previamente por lo que no deberías instalarlo ahora.
grub-install /dev/sda (asumiendo que es tu disco principal)
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score -1):

En este link ya se ha respondido a esta pregunta https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list

espero te sirva.

Saludos

Comment: No me sirvio. ahora tampoco puedo iniciar sesion en linux no sale de la pantalla de login